# Firebase - Cloud Firestore, Problems creating rule for admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Im having a problem with creating firebase rules, I created a field "role" in my 'employees' collection, so there, I want to distinguish each type of users allowed to read/write, etc in the DB. My problem is that for some reason I cant verify if the user trying to read others information is really the admin, in the "isAdministrator" function I cant make the get's to work:

```html
service cloud.firestore {

 // Function: Check if an authenticated employee is admin
 function isAdministrator(){
   //return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 'admin' 
   // || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).role == 'admin';
  return false;
    // (data.child('role').val() == 'admin')
  }
  
  // Function: Check if an employee is authenticated
  // RULES
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
  // Allows only admins and 'owner' to acess his document
  match /employees/{document=**} {
     allow read, write, update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid || isAdministrator();
      allow create, delete, list: if isAdministrator();
    }
  }
}
```

This is how my collection looks like:

[image: Employees collection with roles]

Answer (score 0):

match /databases/{database}/documents must wrap everything, including the function, like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // FUNCTIONS
    // Function: Check if an authenticated employee is admin
    function isAdministrator(){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 'admin' 
                    || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).role == 'admin';
    }
    // RULES
    // Allows only admins and 'owner' to acess his document
    match /employees/{document=**} {
        allow read, write, update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid || isAdministrator();
        allow create, delete, list: if isAdministrator();
    }
  }
}
```